# How to use thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wonder how I could use thread.
When I make many requests through this code my CPU usage gets 100%.

```
public static void GetPage(String url)
{
  try
  {
    // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    if ( myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK )
      Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}",
                        myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);

    // Releases the resources of the response.
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
  }
  catch ( WebException e )
  {
    MessegeBox.Show("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occurred : {0}", e.Status);
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    MessegeBox.Show("\nThe following Exception was raised : {0}", e.Message);
  }
}

void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  new Thread(() =>
  {
    while ( true )
    {
      Getpage();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can make Threads then abort.
I want to send fast request so I don't want to do many Sleeps after each request.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200120/discussion-on-question-by-john-nikolov-how-to-use-thread-c).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the while loop and the process will stops to saturate the CPU.

You can do nothing from your C# code.

Thread is not for doing atoms things faster but at the "same" time.

You depend on the infrastructure of the network and the architecture of the server.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm

Try this:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var thread = new Thread(() => { Getpage(someurl); });
  thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Wait you said "Thread is not for doing atoms things faster but at the "same" time.

" so i have to use async await yes